# how to use ignorecase while matching two ids in js

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive

```
function myfunc()
{

   var x = document.getElementById('MY_DIV').name;
   document.getElementById(x).value=2;
}


      <input type="text" id="MY_DIV" name="MY_DIV1"/>
      <input type="text" id="my_div1" />
      <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="myfunc();">
```

How to use ignorecase in above js code to fill the value 2 in second textbox?

Comment: Erm... `<div id="my_div1">` and `<div id="MY_DIV1">` are two completely different IDs. Same with `<div id="mY_dIV1">` and any other possible combination of capitalisation. You should avoid having IDs like this, of course, but the fact that they can exist means that you should NOT attempt to ignore case.

Comment: but my data is coming from some other site and i have to use it. Can you please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Javascript string case-insensitive comparisons can be performed with
> **string.toUpperCase.**

```
var x = document.getElementById('MY_DIV').name;
x = x.toUpperCase(); //use this line
    if (x == "STRING TO MATCH"){
    }
```

Referenced to [tutorialsPoint Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/regexp_ignorecase.htm) for using ignoreCase property

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript RegExp ignoreCase Property</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var re = new RegExp( "string" );

   if ( re.ignoreCase ){
      document.write("Test1-ignoreCase property is set"); 
   }else{
     document.write("Test1-ignoreCase property is not set"); 
   }
   re = new RegExp( "string", "i" );

   if ( re.ignoreCase ){
      document.write("<br/>Test2-ignoreCase property is set"); 
   }else{
     document.write("<br/>Test2-ignoreCase property is not set"); 
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output

> Test1 - ignoreCase property is not set
>
> Test2 - ignoreCase property is set

Code updated for D.K function

```
function myfunc()
{

    var x = document.getElementById('MY_DIV').name;
    //x = x.toUpperCase();   // check the result with / without un-commenting this line
    
    var re = new RegExp( x );

    if ( re.ignoreCase ){
      document.write("X - Test1-ignoreCase property is set"); 
    }else{
     document.write("X - Test1-ignoreCase property is not set"); 
    }
    re = new RegExp( x, "i" );

    if ( re.ignoreCase ){
      document.write("<br/> X - Test2-ignoreCase property is set"); 
    }else{
     document.write("<br/>X - Test2-ignoreCase property is not set"); 
    }
    x = x.toUpperCase();  // ignoring case
    document.getElementById(x).value=2;
   
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how using `string.toUpperCase` makes JavaScript case-insensitive? Using the `/i` regex modifier has that effect (when using regex, of course), but your comment makes little sense. Also, using regexp doesn't really apply to DOM traversal methods.

Comment: @Marcel the user is requesting the ignoreCase ... so bascially it means that he is not concerned with Case of data and his only concern is data (same or not) ... so bascially we are uppercasing both the input and text to be matched to check if they are same or not

Comment: @Fayeq, thanks. Could you please update your answer to my code. Actually i have seen this already, but not able to implement it :(

Answer (score 1):

Use this in js:

```
   var x = document.getElementById('MY_DIV').name;
   x = x.toLowerCase(); //use this line
   document.getElementById(x).value=2;
```

Comment: any other thing except toLowerCase(). I have read somewhere ignoreCase property of js, but not able to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript is case sensitive** you can use the following but it will not work if your target div id has any upper case characters

```
var x = document.getElementById('MY_DIV').name.toLowerCase();
document.getElementById(x).value=2;
```